# How to use multiple tuples in Python with the "if" command

Tags: python

I've just started Python and don't know how to use Tuples mutiple times,can anyone help me? My code is:

```
import random

A = (
    "Gift Idea AN",
    "Gift Idea AN",
    "Gift Idea AN"
    )

B = (
    "Gift Idea BD",
    "Gift Idea BD",
    "Gift Idea BD"
    )

C = (
    "Gift Idea CM",
    "Gift Idea CM",
    "Gift Idea CM"
    )

print("Welcome to the gift giving thing!")

input("Please pick an event:\n1 = Annaversary\n2 = Birthday\n3 = Christmas")

if 1:
    print(A)
elif 2:
    print(B)
else:
    print(C)
```

Comment: `input` returns a string, so you need to cast it to an integer cause you are checking `if 1:` etc. so you need `int(input("...."))`

Comment: You need to be specific about what error you are getting.

Comment: You need to assign the return value of `input` to a name, then use the name in the conditional statements. `answer = input(....`; `if answer = '1':.....`

Comment: I would expect it is always printing `A`, because `if 1` will always trigger as `1` is "truthy". I think you want to store the result of `input`, like `choice = input(...)`, then check `if choice == '1'...`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are using if 1 this which is always true so it will always print A without going to next condition. So try this

```
import random

A = (
    "Gift Idea AN",
    "Gift Idea AN",
    "Gift Idea AN"
    )

B = (
    "Gift Idea BD",
    "Gift Idea BD",
    "Gift Idea BD"
    )

C = (
    "Gift Idea CM",
    "Gift Idea CM",
    "Gift Idea CM"
    )

print("Welcome to the gift giving thing!")

while True:
      try:
            ip=int(raw_input("Please pick an event:\n1 = Annaversary\n2 = Birthday\n3 = Christmas\n"))
            break
      except ValueError:
            print "That's not a valid input try again"

if ip==1:
    print(A)
elif ip==2:
    print(B)
else:
    print(C)
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because `ip` is a string, and the `if` statement checks for integers. You need to cast to `int()` or check for a string. (i.e. `if ip == '1'`)

Comment: I think you might have an issue with `input` returning a string. Would need to either parse or change to string comparison.

Comment: @kstullich Agreed. If you use `int` you'll want to handle invalid input, though.

Comment: @ryachza/ @kstullich : Updated as per comments